# Exception: Files must reside under the rootDir

Tags: flutter, entity-framework, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to convert my file to a .zip file after getting a list of pdf files but shows an Exception: Files must reside under the rootDir

```
ListTile(
                    title: Text(files[index].path),
                    leading: Icon(Icons.folder_zip_outlined),
                    //   trailing: Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: Colors.redAccent,),
                    onTap: (){
                      final sourceDir = Directory("source_dir");
                      final files = [
                        File(sourceDir.path + "file1"),
                        File(sourceDir.path + "file2")
                      ];
                      try {
                        final zipFile = File("storage/emulated/0/zip/${files[index].path.split('/').last}.zip");

                        ZipFile.createFromFiles(
                            sourceDir: sourceDir, files: files, zipFile: zipFile);
                      } catch (e) {
                        print(e);
                      }
                      // you can add Play/push code over here
                    },
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and here is my solution:

- you have to copy the needed files to the app's root directory
- then you have to pass this new list of files to the zip function

I created a file util class that helps me move the files to the root dir:

```js
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;

class FileUtil {
  static Future<List<File>> copyFilesToRootDirectory(
      List<File> files, String newPath) async {
    List<File> newFilesList = [];
    files.forEach((file) async {
      newFilesList.add(await copyFileToRootDirectory(file, newPath));
    });
    return newFilesList;
  }

  static Future<File> copyFileToRootDirectory(File file, String newPath) async {
    String finalPath = "$newPath/${getFileNameAndType(file)}";
    if (file.path == finalPath) {
      //file already in this path
      return file;
    }
    return await file.copy(finalPath);
  }

  static String getFileNameAndType(File file) {
    return file.path.split("/").last;
  }
}
```

And in the Looger Util class I created this function:

```js
  static Future<File?> zipFiles() async {
    final appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String dbPath = p.join(appDir.path, 'kidlingTeacher.db').toString();
    final List<File> files = [File(dbPath), await FLog.exportLogs()];
    final List<File> filesInRootDir =
        await FileUtil.copyFilesToRootDirectory(files, appDir.path);
    final zipFile = File(p.join(appDir.path.toString(),
        "DIAGNOSTICS-${await getDeviceUUID()} - ${DateTime.now().toUtc().toString()}.zip"));
    try {
      await ZipFile.createFromFiles(
          sourceDir: appDir, files: filesInRootDir, zipFile: zipFile);
      return zipFile;
    } catch (e, s) {
      LoggerUtil.logError(
          text: "zip file process failed",
          className: "logger util",
          methodName: "zipFiles",
          exception: e as Exception,
          stackTrace: s);
    }
    return null;
  }
```